# MongoDB: node-migrate with Mongoose find callback never get executed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) inside my up and down of [node-migrate](https://github.com/tj/node-migrate).
However callback for a simple find query never get executed e.g.

I have an existing User model (users collection with pre-existing documents)
Here's how my up function looks like

```
exports.up = function(done) {    
  User.find().exec(function(err,
    users) {
  done(); //this never get executed??
  });
}
```

**Update**:-
I even tried wrapping query inside 'connected' event handler( below)
but still no luck.

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
     User.find().exec(function(err, users) {
    done(); //this never get executed??
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your find query function because there is no any declaration about your query and simply add `{}` for get all documents. Also check if any error inside exec callback.

```
exports.up = function(done) {    
  User.find({}).exec(function(err, users) { // In find method give empty object declaration for query
    if(err){
      // check has any error here
    }
    done();
  });
}
```

Comment: Tried that  but same issue.

Comment: Did you checked , do you have any error ? Or have you ever debugged , did it finds documents correctly and does it run exec callback function? I think we have to sure about these criterias. Also you can try instead of find().exec , just find({},yourcallbackfunc).

Comment: It does not run exec callback function.I get no error. code just hangs as node-migrate expects done() method to be invoke to signal completion which never gets executed (issue).  I tried find({},yourcallbackfunc) as well .still same issue

Comment: Have you ever checked your node-migrate up function works as expected with trying only done function ? I couldn't understand which case causes problem.

Comment: Yes it works fine if i remove the query and simply call done

Comment: Okay then problem is about mongoose , or any other async call inside .up function. Can you try to call done() in any other async function, eg. setTimeout

Comment: Its definitely an async issue with mongoose. (  done inside setTimeout executes successfully.)

Comment: Are you sure mongoose connection is ok? Please debug your code also step by step.

Comment: Yes connection is ok. if you see my updated question. i have wrapped query inside 'connected' event handler.. and even put log statement inside it ..i can see output of that log statement on the console. so mongoose connection is fine.